# Why is the comment character sequence (/* */) in CSS important?

Tags: css, comments

Why are comments in CSS even considered? I was testing a website out earlier and just put some plain text after a semicolon:

```
#myId {
   property: value; this is my comment
}
```

And no errors were raised, the value still applied to the selector, and everything worked out just fine. Why use `/* */`? I tested it out in Chrome and Firefox. Are there other browsers that might not parse the CSS if I do this that I am not aware of?

Comment: In most programming languages used the /* */ as comment syntax and recommended. No matter how the browser used the comments!!

Comment: The broader question is why [HTML validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Markup_Validation_Service) is not a natural part of the workflow.

Comment: Re *"I tested it out in Chrome and Firefox"*: Firefox ***terminates*** all further CSS processing (at least for the same segment); the following CSS content is *ignored*. Thus it *can* make a difference.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as opinion-based. Many web developers don't take syntactically correct HTML and CSS seriously (masked by web browsers' tolerance), and this is about the consequence of syntactically incorrect CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your browser probably just dropped the "this is my comment". After the ";", it thought that "this is my comment" was a property, but didn't know what it was. But it will drop everything after it until it reaches the "}".

Try something like:

```
#myId {
  border: 1px solid red; this is my comment
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

The blue border won't be displayed, but it should.

Then try:

```
#myId {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

The blue border appears!

So I would use the `/* */` for comments ;P

Comment: Re *"it will drop everything after it until it reaches the "}""*: Yes, that is also my experience. At least with Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

When you insert `/* */`, the browser will just ignore whatever goes behind these symbol. While as you put something like this

```
 #myId {
   property: value; this is my comment
 }
```

The browser will take the " this is my comment " as one of the parse error and go on to the next line of your CSS. You can refer to http://csslint.net to check whether it is an error or not.

Basically, it will just makes your page loads longer because there is error and also makes your work looked untidy. Making comments can always help people to remember something about their codes and help you to debug stuff sometimes.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is: *"Why use `/* */`?"*. The question is *not* about how to properly add comments to CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is part of the syntax of CSS, and I think if your code gets bigger, it can generate many hard-to-find bugs. The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) page *[CSS Syntax Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/)* is talking about the usage.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, browsers are forgiving on errors such as this one. If the browsers encounter an error they simply ignore it and proceed to the next piece of code.

If you want to make sure your CSS is errorfree you may want to validate it with the [CSS Code Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). It's pretty simple to use.

Comment: Or just [HTML validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Markup_Validation_Service)?

Comment: No, browsers are not forgiving in this case. A lot of CSS content may be silently *ignored* due to such a syntax error. See [mogosselin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226048/why-are-comments-in-css-important/21226112#21226112).